# If $f$ has a pole of order $m\ge 1$ in $a$ then $\lim_{z\to a}\vert f(z)\vert=\infty.$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $\Omega\setminus{\{a\}}$ where $a\in \Omega$ and $\ \Omega$  is an open set.

$f$ has a pole of order $m\ge 1$ in $a$ if in a deleted neighborhood of $a$ I can write $$f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{c_{-m}}{(z-a)^k}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k(z-a)^k$$ for $c_{-m}\ne 0.$

Now I would like to prove that it implies that $\lim_{z\to a}\vert f(z)\vert=\infty.$

Denote $R$ the radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k(z-a)^k$ and $0<h<R$ so that $\vert z-a\vert\le h,$

Then we have  $(z-a)^mf(z)=c_{-m}+c_{-m+1}(z-a)+\ldots+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_k(z-a)^{k-m}.$

Not sure how can continue I would like something $\vert f(z)\vert\times\vert z-a\vert^m\ge A_m$ where $A_m$ would be positive constant. I tried the revers inequality, but I have something like $\vert c_{-m}-h(\vert c_{-m+1}\vert\ldots)\vert$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you already have it...almost:

$$|f(z)|=\frac1{|z-a|^m}\left|a_{-m}+a_{m+1}(z-a)+\ldots\right|$$

and now just observe that

$$\left|a_{-m}+a_{m+1}(z-a)+\ldots\right|\xrightarrow[z\to a]{}|a_{-m}|$$

Comment: arf, I should have seen it. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The function
$$
g(z)=(z-a)^mf(z)
$$
has a removable singularity at $a$, with
$$
\lim_{z\to a}g(z)=c_{-m}\ne0
$$
Therefore $|g(z)|$ is bounded away from $0$ in a neighborhood of $a$.

Since
$$
\lim_{z\to a}|f(z)|=
\lim_{z\to a}\frac{1}{|(z-a)^m|}|g(z)|
$$
the squeeze theorem allows to conclude.

Comment: $g(z)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{n-m} (z-a)^n$ is analytic at $a$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, that's the idea

Comment: IMO removable singularity is difficult to understand at the beginning in complex analysis

Comment: @user1952009 That's the very definition of order of a pole.

Comment: The definition is that $f(z) = (z-a)^{-m} g(z)$ where $g$ is analytic, $g(a) \ne 0$

Comment: @user1952009 It depends on  what book you read.